# Intellij + wsl2 + gradle project => no src folder in the project view

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, wsl-2

I imported a Gradle project in Intellij but I can't see the src folder in the project view:
[image]

Here are my settings:
[image]

I've got this error in the logs:

```
2021-06-04 13:57:29,493 [  15049]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - null 
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.data.javaee.JavaeeProjectDataService.lambda$computeOrphanData$0(JavaeeProjectDataService.java:109)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.data.javaee.JavaeeProjectDataService.removeData(JavaeeProjectDataService.java:147)
...
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Cannot load class org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.data.javaee.GradleWebFrameworkSupportProvider (
error: org/jetbrains/plugins/gradle/frameworkSupport/GradleFrameworkSupportProvider,
classLoader=PluginClassLoader(plugin=PluginDescriptor(name=Java EE: Gradle Integration, id=com.intellij.javaee.gradle, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.2\plugins\gradle-javaee, version=211.7442.40, package=null), packagePrefix=null, instanceId=116, state=active)
)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClassInsideSelf(PluginClassLoader.java:346)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.tryLoadingClass(PluginClassLoader.java:233)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:212)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.data.javaee.GradleArtifactPropertiesProvider.<clinit>(GradleArtifactPropertiesProvider.java:31)
... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/plugins/gradle/frameworkSupport/GradleFrameworkSupportProvider
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass2(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1109)
at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.consumeClassData(UrlClassLoader.java:276)
at com.intellij.util.lang.ZipResourceFile.findClass(ZipResourceFile.java:119)
at com.intellij.util.lang.JarLoader.findClass(JarLoader.java:55)
at com.intellij.util.lang.ClassPath.findClassInLoader(ClassPath.java:224)
at com.intellij.util.lang.ClassPath.findClass(ClassPath.java:183)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClassInsideSelf(PluginClassLoader.java:338)
... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.frameworkSupport.GradleFrameworkSupportProvider PluginClassLoader(plugin=PluginDescriptor(name=Java EE: Gradle Integration, id=com.intellij.javaee.gradle, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.2\plugins\gradle-javaee, version=211.7442.40, package=null), packagePrefix=null, instanceId=116, state=active)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:215)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
... 45 more
```

What did I do wrong?

Intellij version: 2021.1.1
Gradle version: 7.0.2

Comment: Show screenshots of what you see. Also please provide the idea.log file (Help | Show Log in ... action) after reproducing. Any errors reported?

Comment: Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-252072. Try deleting the `disabled_plugins.txt` file from the [IDE configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#config-directory) directory.